# php multiple image upload and display each image

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload

i'm struggle with some multiple image upload script.

what i implement to do is , upload multiple image then save each image saved path to variable

so i use later for display .

but when i run script i only can save first upload image path value.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br>
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br>
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br>
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>


<?php
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        $ext = substr(strrchr($name, "."), 1);
        $randName = md5(rand() * time());
        $pathimg = "images/$randName.$ext";
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $pathimg );
        echo '<img src="'.$pathimg.'"; >' ;


    }
}
?>
```

this is upload path ''

for example if i upload 3 images then i want to save this 3 image uploaded path to variable each. so each variable will be $A, $B, $C

or if i upload 4 images i also want to this 4 image path to variable each then use for later

please enlighten me! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect errors while uploading.

Change

```
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
```

to

```
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"] as $key => $tempFile) {
```

Also, after successful upload, append the images into an array.

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"] as $key => $tempFile) {
  // YOUR CODE
  $arr[] = '<img src="'.$pathimg.'"; >' ;
}
```

And print it in a loop.

```
if (! empty($arr)) {
  foreach ($arr as $img) {
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"/>';
  }
}
```